# Excel Office.js - addFromBase64 - in preview

Tags: office-js

One of my customers is looking for more details on addFromBase64   API, and when/whether will it be included in final release  (method is currently available only in public preview)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-workbooks

Insert a copy of an existing workbook into the current one (preview)
 Note
The WorksheetCollection.addFromBase64 method is currently available only in public preview. To use this feature, you must use the preview version of the Office JavaScript library from the Office.js CDN. The type definition file for TypeScript compilation and Intellisense is found at the CDN and DefinitelyTyped. You can install these types with npm install --save-dev @types/office-js-preview. For more information on our upcoming APIs, please visit Excel JavaScript API requirement sets.

This may help them plan better or look for other workaround, as Excel does not expose insertfilefrombase64 at the moment, which is there in Word.

checked online

Comment: any update for this one?

Comment: I’m sorry for the delayed response. The release of this API is delayed due to a dependency and the timeline has not been finalized.